# Tweet's xml format

Tags: tweetsharp

I get ' top tweets ' from twitter as an RSS feed in xml format . 
There is a guid field in that xml format.
There is a long 11 digit number at the end of guid field , is it unique for every tweet ?

Answer (score 3):

GUID stands for [Globally **Unique** Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier), so yes.

Comment: i wanted to know that " is the 11 digit number ( substring of    'string guid ' )   unique for every tweet ? "

Comment: Again, yes. That is the tweet's GUID. Other (non-RSS) API calls may expose the number on its own without the full URL.